# Anonymous implementation of okhttp3.Callback

Tags: android, okhttp, leakcanary

I have recently added a leakcanary to my project to trace the leaks. So during the request to server using `okhttp3` I got the leak of 8mb saying that

`Anonymous implementation of okhttp3.Callback`

So I am wondering is this from the okhttp3 or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Presumably you are performing `apiCall.enqueue(new Callback())` and within this callback you are holding a reference to a activity.

Comment: @azizbekian nice catch! I am calling `getActivity()` inside `apiCall.enqueue(new Callback()`

Comment: @azizbekian should I kept the reference out side of `apiCall.enqueue(new Callback()`?

Comment: Would you describe the use case? Why exactly you need to keep reference to activity? What are you performing in callback?

Comment: You can use `context` instead `getActivity()`

Comment: @azizbekian Actually I am using mailLoopper thread of hosted activity inside `apiCall.enqueue(new Callback()`

Comment: If you need to keep reference to the hosting activity, then you have create a custom response class which implements `Callback`, and saving a reference to the activity in a `WeakReference` in order not to keep a hard reference to the hosting activity.

Comment: yes now i am working on that direction!

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you are performing `apiCall.enqueue(new Callback())` and within this callback you are holding a reference to the hosting activity.